# django ModelChoiceField: is there a query on GET and POST?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Having a FormView where the form has a ModelChoiceField.

```
my_objects = forms.ModelChoiceField(
         queryset=MyObject.objects.all(),
         widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
         empty_label=None
     )
```

Does ModelChoiceField query the Database when the view is accessed via GET and again when it is accessed via POST (i.e. when the form is submit) to get the choices since the view and form object are recreated on each HTTP request?

Comment: For security reasons, it check again database when it is performed via post to ensure that submitted values are presents in queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Yes database is queried on every request.
I'm not sure but the `QuerySet.all` method queries the DB when called, not like for example `QuerySet.filter` that only prepares the query that is executed somewhere later in the request.